# Creating a view with draggable text elements

Tags: cocoa, draggable, subview, nstextview

I am trying to create a view for a kind of brainstorming application like, for example, OmniGraffle, with elements that contain textviews and can be dragged around. (Also, the should be connectable with arrows, but that is not (yet) the problem)

I did my homework and searched via google and read books about cocoa, but there seems to be no similar example around.
Since I am also new to cocoa, I’m a bit helpless here.

The thing I am sure of is, that I need a custom view in which I can create my elements - what I tried until now to do that is:

- First, I searched for the syntax to add subwindows to a window to create my elements. Subwindows, I imagined, would automatically be movable and come to front and so on.
  The problem: As the experienced Cocoa-programmers of you probably  are not surprised, I was stunned to find nothing about anything like that - this seems to be something, that is just not intended in Cocoa?!
- Then I thought about creating subviews that contain a custom view for the title bar drawing (where the user can click to drag the element) and a `NSTextView`.
  Problems:

  - I read, that it is not so clever to create dozens of subviews in a window because that would be very slow (or would that be not so bad in this case because all the subviews would be instances of always the same class?).
  - Also I can’t find out how to load a subview from a nib- or xib-file. Would I need a viewController? Or would that make the dozens-of-instances-problem even worse?
  - And Apple tells you not to overlap subviews (okay, that would be not so important, but I really wonder how the guys at OmniGroup made OmniGraffle...)
- Because of that, I now wanted to do the title-bar-drawing in the surrounding custom view and create the textview programmatically (as I understand, a text-“view“ ist not really a view and takes its functionality from NSCell to reduce all the effort with the views?).
  Problems:

  - Even that failed because I was not able to create a textview that doesn’t fill the complete window (the `initWithFrame:` of the `[[NSScrollView alloc] initWithFrame: aRect]`  just seems to be ignored or do I get that wrong?).
  - Also, there should be some buttons on each element in the final application. I imagine that would be easier to accomplish with a subview from a nib-file for each element?

Well, now that nothing works and the more I read, the more problems seem to occur, I am pretty confused and frustrated.
How could I realize such a program? Could someone please push me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

I created a class for the draggable elements where I save position, size and text in instance variables. In my view, every new element instance is added to an array (for now, this works without a controller). The array is used to draw all the elements in a loop in `drawRect:`. For the text of the element I just use a NSTextFieldCell which is set to the saved text from every element in the same loop.

That way it is also possible to overlap the elements.